# Display the selected row from listview to textBox?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, textbox

How to display the selected row from listview to textBox?

This is how I do int dataGridView:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].ReadOnly = true;
    if (dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count != 0)
    {
        DataGridViewRow row = this.dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0];
        EmpIDtextBox.Text = row.Cells["EmpID"].Value.ToString();
        EmpNametextBox.Text = row.Cells["EmpName"].Value.ToString();
    }
}
```

I tried this:

```
private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ListViewItem item = listView1.SelectedItems[0];
    if (item != null)
    {
        EmpIDtextBox.Text = item.SubItems[0].Text;
        EmpNametextBox.Text = item.SubItems[1].Text;
    }
}
```

Comment: The code should work, what is the actual problem?

Comment: There may be some exception `IndexOutOfRangeException` because sometimes there is no selected item in `ListView`.

Comment: Changing the one line to `ListViewItem item = listView1.SelectedItems.Count > 0 ? listView1.SelectedItems[0] : null;` will cover the out of range issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may want to check if there is a SelectedItem first. When the selection changed, `ListView` would actually unselect the old item then select the new item, hence triggering `listView1_SelectedIndexChanged` twice. Other than that, your code should work:

```
private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (listView1.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
    {
        ListViewItem item = listView1.SelectedItems[0];
        EmpIDtextBox.Text = item.SubItems[0].Text;
        EmpNametextBox.Text = item.SubItems[1].Text;
    }
    else
    {
        EmpIDtextBox.Text = string.Empty;
        EmpNametextBox.Text = string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

// select row listview check in c#

foreach (ListViewItem itemRow in taskShowListView.Items)
            {

```
            if (itemRow.Items[0].Checked == true)
            {

                int taskId = Convert.ToInt32(itemRow.SubItems[0].Text);

                string taskDate = itemRow.SubItems[1].ToString();
                string taskDescription = itemRow.SubItems[2].ToString();



            }


        }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Can you elaborate more your answer?

Answer (score 0):

Simply select the row. Iterate over the list and check which row is selected. Make operation as per the row selected.
Such as,

```cs
private void delete_Items(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    foreach(ListViewItem item in listView1.Items)
    {

      if (item.Selected == true)
      {
          // Code Here...
      }

    }

}
```