# How to get selected item in ListView to TextBox?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

How to get selected item in ListView to TextBox?

```
private void txtautosgn_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (txtautosgn.Text.Length > 1)
    {
        var names = (from autonames in lstDetails
                     where autonames.name.Contains(txtautosgn.Text.Trim())
                     select autonames.name).ToList();

        if (names.Count > 1)
        {
            lstnames.Items.Clear();
            lstnames.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            foreach (string name in names)
            {
                lstnames.Items.Add(name);
            }
            lstnames.SelectedIndex = 0;

        }
        else
        {
            lstnames.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17599358/display-the-selected-row-from-listview-to-textbox

Answer (score 0):

In your method, instead of adding Item in `ListView`, set `ItemsSource` of it like:

```
    var names = (from autonames in lstDetails
                 where autonames.name.Contains(txtautosgn.Text.Trim())
                 select autonames.name).ToList();

    if (names.Count > 1)
    {
        lstnames.Items.Clear();
        lstnames.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        lstnames.ItemsSource = names;
        lstnames.SelectedIndex = 0;

    }
    else
    {
        lstnames.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
```

and in Xaml you can bind `SelectedItem` of `Listview` to `Textbox` as

```
 <Grid>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=lstnames}"></TextBox>
    <ListView x:Name="lstnames"></ListView>
 </Grid>
```